# Catch block avoid Compilation Error?

Tags: exception, compiler-errors, try-catch, unreachable-code

I have the following codes, and it is giving me a compilation error.

> // Program1 -- Compilation error

```
public class ExceptionExample {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        try {
            method();
        } catch (ClassCastException p) {} catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Exception");
        }
    }
    public static void method() {
        try {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

But the following code works after I added some catch blocks.

> // Program 2 - No Compilation error

```
public class ExceptionExample {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        try {
            method();
        } catch (ClassCastException p) {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Exception");
        }
    }
    public static void method() {
        try {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        // Below catch block has been added 
        catch (ClassCastException p) {

        }

        finally {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**Unreachable code at "System.out.println("Hi");"**
I am wondering, how can adding unnecessary catch blocks solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help you get responses, please elaborate on the question that you would like answered. You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for information on how to ask the best questions.

Comment: You're missing the most important information - what actual compilation error are you getting, what's the error message?

Comment: Unreachable code at "System.out.println("Hi");"

Answer (score 0):

Because in the program1 the compiler is confident that the execution flow can never reach the line "System.out.println("Hi");" as there is neither catch block to try  nor some condition
to throw statement,

You can also avoid this error by writing some condition with variable to throw statement like this

```
        int a =0;

        if(a==0)
        throw new NullPointerException();
```

In the program2, of course the catch block never executes but compiler assumes that there is specific catch for try to handle and will stop throwing error.